# Redirect user by their location, not by their browser language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I'm making a website for a company. I have it in 3 languages: English, Norway and Icelandic. I've found out javascripts that redirect user by the language of their browser. Is there any way that I can make the redirect by the location of the user? (like on the mtv.com website). Thank you!

Comment: This is usually a bad idea.  Just because a traveler may *be* in a certain country doesn't mean he wants things served in that LANGUAGE.

Comment: It's a sign making company, so it's more related to business to business. I think it will work good for this project.

Answer (score 0):

grab this library http://www.localeplanet.com/

you can even use [i18n](http://i18next.com/pages/doc_features.html) with/without jQuery

Comment: Which one do you think it's better? I understood that there can be some conflicts with Google. For now I will have 3 .html files, but the client will have 3 different domains. So I want, if the Norway client will access the .com domain to be redirected to the .no website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Geolocalisation, like using [GeoDirection](http://www.geobytes.com/GeoDirection.htm) (doesn't require jQuery).

Here's an example of what you could do :

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesLocationCode,GeobytesCode,GeobytesInternet"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode)=="undefined"
   ||typeof(sGeobytesCode)=="undefined"
   ||typeof(sGeobytesInternet)=="undefined")
{
   // Something has gone wrong with the variables, so set them to some default value,
   // maybe set a error flag to check for later on.
   var sGeobytesLocationCode="unknown";
   var sGeobytesCode="unknown";
   var sGeobytesInternet="unknown";
}
if(sGeobytesLocationCode=="CAQCMONT")
{
   // Visitors from Montreal would go here
   window.open("enter Montreal URL here");
}else if(sGeobytesCode=="QC")
{
   // Visitors from Quebec would go here
   window.open("enter Quebec URL here");
}else if(sGeobytesInternet=="CA")
{
   // Visitors from Canada would go here
   window.open("enter Canada URL here");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already saw this option, but I don't like that they have a advertisment pop-up for every 1 of 50 redirects.

Answer (score 0):

I could also propose you [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding) with the help of [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding). It allow you to get a lot of information about the user localisation like is country. After with some condition you could redirect your user at the right page.